# First control which accepts keyboard input

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, mdichild

I have an application which displays different MDI forms. A form contains huge amounts of visual components, and somehow the focus is lost after the form is displayed. I need to find the first control (with the lowest set `TabOrder`) on the form which accept keyboard input (with a text field e.g. TEdit, TMemo, etc), so I can set the [active control](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.ActiveControl) to it.

LE: all the controls are created at runtime, and the order of the creation is different based on the business logic.

Comment: Maybe iterate over all controls and check CanFocus?

Comment: Ok, with that cleared up, what do you mean by "first"?  Upperleftmost?  With respect to the form's client area?  Lowest `TabOrder`?  Something else?

Comment: Then loop through the controls looking for the control with TabOrder = 0. (Or just set the ActiveControl by name in your code in the FormCreate event or in the IDE at design time.)

Comment: If you set the `ActiveControl` at design-time, the VCL will set that control as focused when the Form is displayed.  You should not have to hunt for a control to manually assign to `ActiveControl` at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau & all - I forgot to mention something important, all the controls are created at runtime, so I need to go hunting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...and somehow the focus is lost after the form is displayed.

My choice would be to answer why that happens and to fix the source of the problem, rather then fixing its implications.

But to answer the question, you are looking for [`Form.SelectFirst`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.SelectFirst).

Comment: At this moment it is very difficult to fix all the issues from the components and from the custom framework used.